# Find a formula for all the points on the hyperbola $x^2 - y^2 = 1$? whose coordinates are rational numbers.

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

So, I know that we first need to have an initial point. The answers I have say it's $(-1, 0)$ which makes sense because it satisfies the equation. But for example $(1, 0)$ satisfies it too. Why did we choose $(-1, 0)$?
In general, how do we go about choosing the initial point?

Comment: $(-1,0)$ is a good choice. So is $(1,0)$.

Comment: Any initial point will work, this is a quadratic so any line through initial point goes through it once more.

Comment: So in general, is it a matter of trial and error? or is there a good way to find the initial point?

Comment: After answering this question, I've been left in doubt: After you find your initial point, what is your method to come up with many solutions?

Comment: @lana I recommend you do not accept someone's answer too quickly. Take time to analyze every answer. There was another answer posted that you did not look at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y=a/b$

$$X=\sqrt { \frac {a^2 + b^2} {b^2}}=\frac 1 b \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

Now, we just need $a^2+b^2$ to be a square, i.e $a^2+b^2=c^2$ be pythagorean triples.

One nice parametrization is to let $a=p^2-q^2, b=2pq$, then $a^2+b^2=(p^2+q^2)^2$, so

$$X=\frac  {p^2+q^2}{2pq}$$

So (part of) our solutions are $(X,Y)=\left(\frac {p^2+q^2}{2pq},\frac {p^2-q^2}{2pq}\right)$.

All the solutions can be found if you parametrize all the pythagorean triples.

Comment: You should explain how to find the initial point according to the question.

Comment: Would you consider "pick an easy Pythagorean triple like $3,4,5$" valid?

Answer (score 3):

The constraint equation,

$$ x^2-y^2 = 1,$$

describes a hyperbola.

We start by picking a rational point on the hyperbola, an easy one is $(1,0)$, lets call this point $A$. Then we draw a line with a rational slope, call it $l$, passing through the point $A$ and elsewhere on the parabola, lets call the point of intersection $B=(x_b,y_b)$.

The equation of the line is,

$$ y = m(x-x_a)+y_a \Rightarrow y = m(x-1), $$

sine we are interested in the intersection of this line with the hyperbola we will substitute it into,

$$ x^2-y^2 = 1,$$

obtaining,

$$ x^2 - m^2(x-1)^2 = 1,$$

which can be simplified to,

$$ x^2 + \frac{2m^2}{1-m^2}x - \frac{m^2+1}{1-m^2} = 0,$$

now this is a quadratic equation for $x$ in terms of the rational number $m$. The points which satisfy this equation lie on both the line, $l$, and our hyperbola. There are two points we know of which do this, one is $A=(1,0)$ the other is $B=(x_b,y_b)$. This means we can factor this equation because we know one of the roots is $x=1$.

Factoring $(x-1)$ out of the left hand side we get,

$$ \left(x-1 \right)\left(x+\frac{m^2+1}{1-m^2} \right) = 0,$$

which gives two solutions,

$$x=1 \qquad x=\frac{m^2+1}{m^2-1},$$

the first is just $x_a=1$ which we knew and the other is $x_b$ which we can see is rational.

$$ x_b =  \frac{m^2+1}{m^2-1} \qquad y_b = m \left( \frac{m^2+1}{m^2-1}-1\right)=\frac{2m}{m^2-1} \qquad m\in \mathbb{Q}$$

If we want the solution parameterized in terms of integers, say $p$ and $q$, we can let $m=p/q$ and make the appropriatie substitutions.

Comment: Hello, how do we know that these are all the rational points on the parabola?

Comment: Hi @Marc. First note that for any pair of rational points we can connect them with a line which has a rational (or undefined) slope. Second note that the point B only had to be "a rational point on the hyperbola", no special assumption was made about this point beyond that; the fact that the set of such points is nonempty can be easily demonstrated. Now B cannot be distinct from A and simultaneously lie on a vertical line which contains A; the hyperbola only admits one solution when x=1. Therefore the slope m exists and is rational. The rest is just algebra.

Answer (score 1):

The choice $(-1,0)$ is good. So is $(1,0)$. Any rational point on the curve is a good choice. For instance we could choose $x=5/4$ and $y=3/4$. But simple is better, it makes the arithmetic nicer.